# Only part of the QPixmap is displayed

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to set pixmap to my QLabel. Problem is , not whole image is displayed in the label, i.e only small part of the image is displayed. Here is the code :

```
QPixmap pix("c:\\images\\myimg.png"));
mLabel->setPixmap(pix);
```

What can be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try setting pixmap size to label size

```
mLabel->setFixedSize(pix.size());
```

Comment: Please, consider adding your own answer to this problem, so others can  benefit of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep aspect ratio of the image you must do that:

```
QPixmap pix("c:\\images\\myimg.png");
pix = pix.scaled(QSize(mLabel->width(),mLabel->height()), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
mLabel->resize(pix.size());
mLabel->setPixmap(pix);
```

If you don't want to keep aspect ratio of the image you must do that:

```
QPixmap pix("c:\\images\\myimg.png");
pix = pix.scaled(QSize(mLabel->width(),mLabel->height()), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
mLabel->setPixmap(pix);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Label was not added in layout. After adding it, it works.